# Como puedo crear un Sidebar en Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy siguiendo este ejemplo https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/others/SideBar para crear un sideBar en qtcreator, pero note que para realizarlo el propietario del ejemplo usa qtdesigner, yo no quiero usarlo, necesito hacerlo todo desde codigo

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    ui->widget->addAction(QString("Action %1").arg(i),
                          QIcon(QString(":/icons/icon%1").arg(i)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

estaba intentando poner el sidebar en el windows pero no se muestra

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
  ui->setupUi(this);
  SideBar *widget=new SideBar();
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    widget->addAction(QString("Action %1").arg(i),
                          QIcon(QString(":/icons/icon%1").arg(i)));
  QVBoxLayout *ql= new QVBoxLayout();
  ql->addWidget(widget);

  this->setLayout(ql);
}
    
      return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Qt designer genera un XML. Al compilar, ese XML se convierte en código c++ que puedes revisar para ver cómo ha creado el sidebar

Comment: @eferion pero quisiera no usar xml, se puede lograr todo desde codigo?

Comment: @eyllanesc podrias ayudarme?

Comment: Revisa el código que se genera automáticamente. Cuando diseñas ventanas con Qt, en la clase que representa la ventana tienes que incluir un archivo `ui_[NombreVentana].h`. Este archivo no le has creado tu sino que lo genera automáticamente Qt cada vez que se *compila* el XML que genera el editor. Si pones el cursor sobre el include a ese archivo `ui` y pulsas F2 accederás al código que genera la ventana que estás diseñando con el editor

Comment: @tucker En mi codigo solo uso el xml para posicionar el sidebar pero el codigo del sidebar esta escrito en C++: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/others/SideBar/sidebar.cpp. Si no quieres usar el .xml entonces no deberias usarlo para todo ya que tu lo estas sobreescribiendo

Comment: @eyllanesc lo borre pero ahora no me muestra nada

Comment: Justamente eso, tu tienes que usar layouts para posicionar el sidebar y los otros elementos de tu ventana

Comment: @eyllanesc he modificado mi pregunta, puse mi codigo en el que estoy usando layout

Comment: @eyllanesc al final no lo logre creo que debo usar el xml